# I like to get table text from <tr> <td> using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is the trial I tried so far.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

url ='http://marketdata.krx.co.kr/mdi#document=080120&547c5e15ef32e37dc099b89d69ac8970-[object%20HTMLDivElement]=1&547c5e15ef32e37dc099b89d69ac8970-[object%20HTMLDivElement]=2&547c5e15ef32e37dc099b89d69ac8970-[object%20HTMLDivElement]=1&547c5e15ef32e37dc099b89d69ac8970-object%20HTMLDivElement]=1'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@name="upclss"]')
all_options = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
for option in all_options :
if option.text == "원자재":
    option.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    another = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@class="active"]')
    another.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    table = soup.findChildren('table')[0]
    rows = table.findChildren('tr')
    for row in rows:
        cells = row.findChildren('td')
        for cell in cells:
            cell_content = cell.getText()
            print(cell_content)
```

What shall I do more to get below table contents from the above url and print it?
Many thanks!!

Comment: Can you include a snippet of the HTML that you are trying to get?

Comment: It's about ETF, kind of like a fund. Below table says code, company, ETF name and so on..I'm trying to automize the query so I select "원자재", which is Korean word for "raw materials". I succeed in automate clicking it...but have trouble getting the actual data.

Comment: As a first guess I would suggest looking at your result for `html` and making sure that your HTML is coming through correctly. And why are you using `selenium`? Can't you extract the HTML using `urlopen`?

Comment: I tried to select the queries, which is the type of ETFs, and refresh the web browser. Come to think of it, it seems I used the same html source from the start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you get it from page source? I know you're using python but in Java I would solve this in this way:

I would handle the page source as a String and get a substring which starts with `<table>` and ends whith 
`</table>` or whatever you want...

From this I would extract my wanted values in the same way - Building a substring starting with the `<td>-`tag and ending with the `</td>-`tag.

The remaining text is the table data text you see on the web page.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm pretty new to Java..could you detail it??

Comment: It's hard to tell...I never used python. Let me say it this way: You need to find a way to get a string of a string by using python. The webdriver API of selenium can print the page source for you: Driver.getPageSource();

Comment: Save the output of this in a string variable and extract your values from it.

Answer (score 0):

The output(value) of the `html = driver.page_source` will help, but I assume this will work as well:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

url ='http://marketdata.krx.co.kr/mdi#document=080120&547c5e15ef32e37dc099b89d69ac8970-[object%20HTMLDivElement]=1&547c5e15ef32e37dc099b89d69ac8970-[object%20HTMLDivElement]=2&547c5e15ef32e37dc099b89d69ac8970-[object%20HTMLDivElement]=1&547c5e15ef32e37dc099b89d69ac8970-object%20HTMLDivElement]=1'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@name="upclss"]')
all_options = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
for option in all_options :
    if option.text == "원자재":
        option.click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        another = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@class="active"]')
        another.click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)                       
        tds = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table/tr/td")
        for td in tds :
            print(td.text)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems not working in my computer. T-T

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it was solved within selenium, not though soup...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

url = '...'
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@name="upclss"]')
all_options = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
for option in all_options :
    print(option.text)
    option.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    another = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@class="active"]')
    another.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    header = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[@class="CI-GRID-HEADER-TABLE"]').text
    other = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[@class="CI-GRID-BODY-TABLE"]').text
    print(header)
    print(other)
```